# Writing 1.0 web components on top of 0.5?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

Another dev team I am working with is building out a bunch of web components using polymer 0.5, but the issue is that it is really just Beta imo.  So now that 1.0 is out, I wanted to build on top of their 0.5 stuff with 1.0.

They know they will be refactoring at some point and dear goodness there is a lot of differences.  They seem to want to just keep chugging along and do their own then then migrate later.

The issue is that if i follow suit, they will eventually modify everything and then i will need to modify everything.

Can i just build 1.0 on top of their stuff in order to circumvent this refactor?  I tried to tell them to just do it in 1.0 but their manager wont budge.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried doing this on my team at Google and it's incredibly difficult to do. I really couldn't recommend it. As another answerer commented, they clobber each other's global `Polymer` variable, but also the version dependencies with Bower are super difficult to get any sense around.

You could recommend tools like [polyup](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polyup) to help automate the process. We did it on our team and while it wasn't exactly trivial, it's definitely worth the time spent: which is often less than you think. [Here's a Lighting Talk from the Polymer Summit last year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maygsoPKLpE) which walks you through the general process.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, since both versions create a `Polymer` global variable, both are bound to overlap.

Comment: Yeah, thats where I was having issues in terms of doing things, unless I managed to update Polymer1.0 to point to a new global "Polymer1" and work off of that, but unlikely